# Copy data from a column into a new column with loop

Tags: excel, vba

```
Rows  | Ref1    |   Ref2  | Ref3|   Final Ref    
3     |   aa    |    bb   | cc  |   aa    
3     |   aa    |    bb   | cc  |   bb    
3     |   aa    |    bb   | cc  |   cc    
2     |   as    |    al   |     |   as    
2     |   as    |    al   |     |   al
```

The vba below automates the creation of the 'Final Ref' column.  The value for this is taken from the other columns.  E.g. there are 3 duplicate rows with the same references; I need Ref1 from the first row, Ref2 from the second row and Ref3 from the third row.  Then for the next 2 rows, which are duplicates, I need Ref1 from the first row and Ref2 from the second row etc.

This is what I have so far.  I'd like the range to be dynamic, based on the longest row.  I have to type in a value at the moment. I have vba separately to select a used range but I don't know how to combine the two.  Thanks in advance.

```
Sub CopyRowPasteRef()
Dim rngToConvert As Range
Dim rngRow As Range
Dim rngCell As Range

'incremental step to keep track of rows
Dim writeRow As Integer
writeRow = 1

'The entire range we are converting
Set rngToConvert = Sheets("Sheet11").Range("A1:E6")

'Loop through each row
For Each rngRow In rngToConvert.Rows

    'Loop through each cell (field)
    For Each rngCell In rngRow.Cells

        'ignore that first row
        If rngCell.Column > 1 And rngCell.Value <> "" Then

            'Write that row header
            Sheets("Sheet12").Cells(writeRow, 1).Value = rngRow.Cells(1, 1)

            'Write this non-null value
            Sheets("Sheet12").Cells(writeRow, 2).Value = rngCell.Value

            'Increment Counter
            writeRow = writeRow + 1
        End If
    Next rngCell
Next rngRow
End Sub
```

How can I add the vba below to the vba above to incorporate a dynamic range based on used cells?

```
Range("A1").Resize(Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row, _
  Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
  SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Column).Select
```

Comment: We won't code for you, but if you give it a shot, we can help you with individual problems and questions.

Comment: google - remove duplicates

Comment: Thank you for making the data inline, I didn't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in E2 and copy down:

```
=INDEX(B2:D2,COUNTIFS($B$1:B2,"=" &B2,$C$1:C2,"=" & C2,$D$1:D2,"=" &D2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this!